# Postman Oauth2 call works, however same call in Jquery fails (web extension)

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, oauth, laravel-5.1, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have been using Oauth2 using Postman and it works just fine.  I get the token as expected.

[image: Postman Oauth]

However when I try this in code, it makes everything but I am never returned the code to use (the code is in my database, but it isn't returned from the jquery call).

```
function validate(redirectURL) {
  console.log('start validate function');


  var clientID2 = "CLIENTID HERE";
  var redirectURL2 = browser.identity.getRedirectURL();
  let m = redirectURL.match(/[#\?](.*)/);
  if (!m || m.length < 1)
    return null;
  let params = new URLSearchParams(m[1].split("#")[0]);
    let tokenurl = "http://localhost:8000/oauth/access_token";
  // tokenurl += `?client_id=${clientID2}`;
  // tokenurl += `?client_secret=${clientSecret}`;
  // tokenurl += `&grant_type=authorization_code`;
  // tokenurl += `&code=${params.get("code")}`;
  // tokenurl += `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectURL2)}`;
  console.log('validate function tokenurl '+ tokenurl);
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: tokenurl,
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    },
    data : {
      client_id : clientID2,
      client_secret : "CLIENT ID SECRET",
      redirect_uri : redirectURL2,
      grant_type : "authorization_code",
      code : params.get("code"),
    }
  })
    .done(function( msg ) {
      console.log('Done return for validate call');
      // console.log( "Token Save Called: " + msg );
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log('Fail return for validate call');
      if(textStatus){
        console.log('validate call returned textStatus-' + textStatus);
      }
      if(errorThrown){
        console.log('validate call returned errorThrown-'+errorThrown);
      }
      console.log('Fail return for validate call Finish');
    })
    .always(function( xhr, status ) {
       console.log('finish validate call ajax request');
     });
}


function authorize() {
  console.log('authorize2');
  const redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL();
  console.log('redirectURL');
  console.log(encodeURIComponent(redirectURL));
  console.log(redirectURL);
  const clientID = "CLIENTID HERE";
  const scopes = ["openid", "email", "profile"];
  let authURL = "http://localhost:8000/oauth/authorize";
  authURL += `?client_id=${clientID}`;
  authURL += `&grant_type=authorization_code`;
  authURL += `&client_secret=4c7f6f8fa93d59c45502c0ae8c4a95b`;
  authURL += `&response_type=code`;
  authURL += `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectURL)}`;
  // authURL += `&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' '))}`;

  console.log('redirectURL');
  console.log(redirectURL);
  console.log('authURL');
  console.log(authURL);

  return browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    interactive: true,
    url: authURL
  });
}


function getAccessToken() {
  console.log('call authorize');
  return authorize().then(validate);
}

console.log('call getAccessToken');
getAccessToken();
```

I get no data returned and the console logs put out the word error.  The functions are getting called and getting to my backend because it is making and storing the final code in the database.

I am using this laravel oauth package
https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel with version 5.1

I am using this in a firefox webextension on Firefox Developer Edition running version 54 which supports Oauth2 calls (based on documentation).

Comment: What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to install and use the extension?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].